# Sideploading apps in multi-user setups

Tags: multi-user, side-loading, f-droid

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note Tab Pro 12.2 with several users defined.  I would like to side-load on-device some APKs not available in the Google Play Store to the other accounts — specifically, to first side-load F Droid then use it for further apps.  I managed to do that in my Moto X Force, but not in the Galaxy, I guess due to it using an older Android version.  Is there any user-definable setting to do that?

Comment: How do you side-load apps? Via `adb` or on-device using the akp files?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification request.  On-device with APKs.